# Creating a test class for Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

The following is my Apex Trigger.  It is a validation Trigger on Sampling_*c which will validate that Country*_c is a Valid country using Validation_country_*c.  When it validates Country*_c it will look into State_province_*c and will then validate that it is actually a state So .. If Country*_c = US and State_province_*c = CA then we are okay.  But IF Country*_c = US and State_province_*c = ZZ221(whatever) it should fail.  Now these condition checks only triggers when Override*_c = 'Yes'.  Now how would I go about creating a test class for this..

This is my Trigger.

```
   trigger OverrideAddressTrigger on Sampling__c (before insert) {

    // Top level map is keyed by Country. Inner Map is keyed by Region
    Map<String, Validation_Country__c> validCountries = new Map<String,Validation_Country__c>();
    Map<String, Map<String, Validation_Region__c>> validRegions = new Map<String, Map<String, Validation_Region__c>>();
    // ...

    For(Validation_Country__c obj : [Select Id,Country_Name__c,Transportation_Zone__C FROM Validation_Country__c]){
        validCountries.put( obj.Transportation_Zone__C,obj );
          System.debug(validCountries);
    }

    For(Validation_Region__c objR : [Select Id,Country_Key__c,Description__c,Name FROM Validation_Region__c]){
        String countryKey = objR.Country_Key__c;

        Map<String, Validation_Region__c> regionMap = validRegions.get(countryKey);
        // Maybe rework to use Map.containsKey rather than null check. Would be cleaner.

        if(regionMap == null) {
            regionMap = new Map<String, Validation_Region__c>();
            validRegions.put(countryKey, regionMap);
        }
        string regionKey = objR.Description__c; 
        regionMap.put( regionKey,objR);
    }

    For( Sampling__c s : Trigger.new){
        If((s.Country__c != null) && (S.Override__c == 'Yes')){
            String countryKey = s.Country__c;
            String regionKey = s.State_Province__c;

            If(validCountries.containsKey(countryKey) && validRegions.containsKey(countryKey)) {
                // The country appears to be valid and there are possible Region matches
                Validation_Country__c vc = validCountries.get(countryKey);

                If(validRegions.get(countryKey).containsKey(regionKey)) {
                    // The Region belongs to the country
                    Validation_Region__c vr = validRegions.get(countryKey).get(regionKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I've been watching, and reading posts and tutorials and I believe this is pretty much all I need to do.  Suggestions?

```
@IsTest
public class OverrideTest {

    static testmethod void addressOverride(){

      Sampling__c s = new Sampling__c();

      s.Override__c = 'Yes';
      s.Country__c = 'US';
      s.State_Province__c = 'CA';
      s.Zip_Postal_Code__c = '93003';

      insert S;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger also needs to fit the additional criteria that your trigger has.  It looks like you need a 'Validation_Region__c' object also.

Have you run the test yet in Eclipse?  It will show you what lines are not covered in your trigger from the test.  From there you can adapt the rest of your test method to make it fit these criteria.

Also, you should have assert statements to ensure that the data you expect at the end of the trigger is correct.

Comment: Oh I never even thought about trying a test in eclipse.. Thanks